# What does "conflicting pattern ignored" mean when loading polyglossia with the German language?

Tags: polyglossia

Please see my MWE:

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
%\usepackage[german=swiss]{csquotes}
%\usepackage[locale=DE]{siunitx}
\setdefaultlanguage[%babelshorthands=true
]{german}
%\setotherlanguage[variant = british]{english}
%\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

The moment, I load the german language, I am getting the error:

> ! Conflicting pattern ignored.
>
> \select@language ...\the \csname l@#1\endcsname )}
>
> \fi \fi \xpg@initial@setup...

What is happening here? I don't understand the error.

Comment: I get no error from the example.

Comment: This can happen after an update or when new languages are installed: lualatex gets confused about the numbers associated with the hyphenation patterns. Recreate the lualatex format.

Comment: I don't know. You are the third with this problem in the last weeks I'm aware of.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From Ulrikes comment:

> This can happen after an update or when new languages are installed:
>   LuaLaTeX gets confused about the numbers associated with the
>   hyphenation patterns. Recreate the LuaLaTeX format!

For MiKTeX this would mean:

*MiKTeX x.x* -> *Maintenance* -> *Settings*:

Tab *Formats* -> *lualatex* -> Button *Build*

Comment: That's so crazy. I couldn't get LuaLaTeX to work with babel (or polyglossia) + biblatex. I've got different errors until I also got this one. After rebuilding LuaLaTeX, it works. Big +1