# Biblatex 2.9 is broken with Babel 3.9k under MiKTeX

Tags: biblatex, babel

I was unable to find babel bugtracker, so I'll post here in the search of help.

Babel 3.9k seems to be broken under MiKTeX.
Here is the part of the log file:

```
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/latex/babel-french/frenchb.ldf")
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/latex/babel-german/german.ldf"
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/latex/babel-german/germanb.ldf"
! Conflicting pattern ignored.
\bbl@ev@luatex@patterns ...}', '\the \language ')}
                                                  \fi \fi
l.183 \ldf@finish\CurrentOption

?
```

And here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage{hyperref}

\RequirePackage[czech,danish,english,french,german,italian,polish,portuguese,spanish,russian]{babel}
\RequirePackage[bibencoding=utf-8,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book(
    book,
    author = {Joe First | Bob Third},
    title = {Book title},
    langid = {english},
    year = 2013,
    url = {http://www.example.com}
)
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

It doesn't matter if I use pdflatex or lualatex.
Here is a question on biblatex bugtracker: https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/246

Comment: Try it is helps to recreate the formats. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/184710/what-does-conflicting-pattern-ignored-mean-when-loading-polyglossia-with-the-g. And I hope you don't compile this document with lualatex: inputenc doesn't work with lualatex.

Comment: This is just an mwe to show the problem. It fails with both luaatex and normal pdflatex. Yes, inputenc is incorrect, I have the correct instructions in the original files.

Comment: Recreated all formats (twice). No effect.

Comment: You seem to have a multiuser installation. Did you recreate the formats as user too? Did you update as user too? (Your example works fine for me on a current miktex)

Comment: No, I have single user installation (i. e. all files installed to Program Files/MiKTeX). Just updated formats as user, still doesn't work.

Comment: Show the log-file.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/georgthegreat/30501c5a3192c3342c1f

Comment: That's not the log-file but the terminal output. But it shows that you are using (in the format) babel 3.8m and not as you claim babel 3.9k. So I doubt very much that you updated the correct format files. Run `initexmf --dump` in a cmd-window.

Comment: Sorry for that. Here is the log output (it is incomplete due to CTRL+C clicked): https://gist.github.com/georgthegreat/2d9a65d558fbcc02f23a Here is initexmf output: https://gist.github.com/georgthegreat/8c6b931adec10aebfaad

Comment: Yes, I also noticed babel version mismatch. I found the source file — they are of 3.9k version, I've reran initexmf -u, but version is still the same. Something stucked somewhere?

Comment: Well the format is new but babel is not uptodate. Run on the command line `mpm --find-updates` *and* `mpm --admin --find-updates`. If one of them shows babel then install it with `mpm --update=babel`. If none of them shows babel then try to find out with `kpsewhich babel.sty` where the outdated babel is located.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem due to a straw file in the TeX tree

Comment: I had the same problem after updating MikTeX. Solution: In the MikTeX-Settings dialog (run as administrator), "updating formats" alone didn't work. I had to go to the tab "Formats", where "lualatex" was marked "excluded". After removing the "excluded" flag, press the "apply" button, the go back to the tab "General" in the Settings menu, press "update formats". Afterwads, start the settings as normal user (!), the that in the "Formats" tab, LuaTeX is not excluded, and recreate the formats again.

Answer (score 1):

Found an outdated cached hyphen.cfg via kpsewhich, removed it manually.
The problem is gone