# no hyphenation i greek polyglossia

Tags: polyglossia, greek

i have problem with my texmaker.it cant hyphenates the Greek words(and not only).i use miktex 2.9 and texmaker 4.3,windows Xp and i have downloaded latex in D:\latex install and after that i installed in D:\latex. i think miktex and texmaker programs is in C:\programs files...
thanks for your time.
Here are the start of my document and the warnings logs:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,amsthm,mathrsfs}
\usepackage{latexsym,graphicx,indentfirst}
\usepackage{ctable}
\usepackage{nopageno}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{xcolor,calc}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{calligra}

%       Ρυθμίσεις Γλώσσας

\setdefaultlanguage[variant=monotonic,numerals=arabic]{greek}
\setotherlanguage[variant=british]{english}
\newcommand{\en}{\selectlanguage{english}}
\newcommand{\gr}{\selectlanguage{greek}}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{GFS Didot}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\onehalfspacing
\textheight =23cm
\setmainfont{FreeSerif}
\setsansfont{FreeSans}
\setmonofont{FreeMono}
\usepackage{microtype}
```

Log contents:

```
Package polyglossia Warning: No hyphenation patterns were loaded for `Greek'
(polyglossia) I will use \language=\l@nohyphenation instead on i
nput line 22.
\l@greek = a dialect from \language\l@nohyphenation
Package polyglossia Warning: No hyphenation patterns were loaded for Monotonic
Greek
(polyglossia) I will use the patterns loaded for \l@greekinstead
on input line 30.
\l@monogreek = a dialect from \language\l@greek
Package polyglossia Warning: No hyphenation patterns were loaded for Ancient Gr
eek
(polyglossia) I will use the patterns loaded for \l@greekinstead
on input line 35.
\l@ancientgreek = a dialect from \language\l@greek
\@attic@num=\count153
)
Package polyglossia Info: Default language is greek.
("D:\latex install\tex\latex\polyglossia\gloss-english.ldf"
File: gloss-english.ldf polyglossia: module for english
)
Package polyglossia Info: Option: english variant=british.
Package polyglossia Warning: No hyphenation patterns were loaded for British En
glish
(polyglossia) I will use the patterns for US English instead on
input line 20.
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The warning means that your TeX distribution lacks support for Greek hyphenation, either because it has been disabled or it is not installed.

Answer (score 3):

After lot of search and try i find something that worked for me in the end.
i just followed this post
[What does "conflicting pattern ignored" mean when loading polyglossia with the German language?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/184710/what-does-conflicting-pattern-ignored-mean-when-loading-polyglossia-with-the-g/185234#185234) 
hope iit will help others too.